# Wordpress - Keep the original blog post date but add a second, last updated date

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I use this snippet to add recently updated beside a post date if it's updated:

```
add_filter('the_title' , 'add_update_status');
function add_update_status($html) {
    //First checks if we are in the loop and we are not displaying a page
    if ( ! in_the_loop() || is_page() )
        return $html;


//Instantiates the different date objects
$created = new DateTime( get_the_date('Y-m-d g:i:s') );
$updated = new DateTime( get_the_modified_date('Y-m-d g:i:s') );
$current = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d g:i:s') );

//Creates the date_diff objects from dates
$created_to_updated = date_diff($created , $updated);
$updated_to_today = date_diff($updated, $current);

//Checks if the post has been updated since its creation
$has_been_updated = ( $created_to_updated -> s > 0 || $created_to_updated -> i > 0 ) ? true : false;

//Checks if the last update is less than n days old. (replace n by your own value)
$has_recent_update = ( $has_been_updated && $updated_to_today -> days < 7 ) ? true : false;

//Adds HTML after the title
$recent_update = $has_recent_update ? '<span class="label label-warning">Recently updated</span>' : '';


    //Returns the modified title
    return $html.'&nbsp;'.$recent_update;
}
```

I want my post to show the following:
Published on October 8th, 2012 at 9:07 am, Last Updated on November 6th, 2013 at 11:03 am

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use these action hooks of WordPress when new post is created and updated. while creating new post, use insert hook and while updating post, use save hook of WordPress.

Create a post meta which stores time of post created and post updated as shown below.

//when new post is added or updated

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post');
function my_save_post($post_id){

    if(empty(get_post_meta($post_id, 'created_on', true))) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'created_on', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));    
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'updated_on', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));

}
```

Now when you need to show this created and updated time separated into your theme, use these functions as shown below:

To show created time

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'created_on', true);
```

To show updated time

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'updated_on', true);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the above code? There is an error

Comment: When I copied the above code under"//when new post is added" the whole website went down.

Comment: Above code works for me. You need to copy above code in your functions.php file of active wordpress theme or in any plugin file.

Comment: I used that in one of the plugins functions.php and you are right, there is no error, however, I can't see the updated date in the post. Do I have to do any further steps?

Comment: I updated above code, it was also updating created_on time while updating post. So I added condition for that.  To show created_on and updated_on time, you need to make changes in your there. Please check above instructions.

Comment: This code is well tested and working. You can check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99421/discussion-between-sam-and-alpesh-panchal).

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this to your post template:

```html
Published on <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, Last modified on <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?>
```